# Sticky Menu with Hide the sticky menu on scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, themes

I am trying to add a sticky menu on my webpage. The sticky menu has to go away if I scroll down and It has to appear when I scroll up. I have gone over the internet and found some answers. But it is not working as expected. I tried 2 cases.

**Case 1:**

I tried below CSS and JS:

**CSS:**

```
@media (min-width: 769px) {
    .main-navigation {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0px;
        z-index: 99;
    }
}
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  var previousScroll = 0;
  $(window).scroll(function(){
       var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
       
       if (currentScroll >= previousScroll){
           $('#primary-menu').addClass('menu-toggle');
       } else {
           $('#primary-menu').removeClass('menu-toggle');
       }
       previousScroll = currentScroll;
    });
  
});
```

When I try the above code, it is working well but sometimes the sticky menu is flickering like a flashlight.

Then I tried the next case.

**Case 2:**

**CSS:**

```
@media (min-width: 769px) {
    .main-navigation {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        width:100%;
        z-index: 99;
    }
}
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  var previousScroll = 0;
  $(window).scroll(function(){
       var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
       
       if (currentScroll >= previousScroll){
           $('#primary-menu').addClass('menu-toggle');
       } else {
           $('#primary-menu').removeClass('menu-toggle');
       }
       previousScroll = currentScroll;
    });
  
});
```

In this case, it is not flickering. But it is overlapping with the header. Please look at the [image here](https://ibb.co/6BSYFhH).

Actually, the menu has to come after the header. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Looks like all client side code.  Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's best if you make a reproducible example. Or at least add a short html and css. This way you get help faster.